# disable body when iframe window is open

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to make a box, for some subscription purpose. How it should be :

- When a user clicks a button
- A iframe window opens
- And the user is able to insert data in the fields.

It looks pretty simple and actually it really is. 
With the use of jquery and css i could create a iframe box. But, the real problem i faced was this :

- The user has opened the window within the page
- But, he could still select the background links.

> So, i need to disable the body or something like *unclickable*, when the iframe is opened.

Comment: show us what you've done so far.

Comment: You could place a `div` with `position:fixed` that occupies the whole screen, give it a high `z-index` and then give the iframe box a slightly higher `z-index`.

Comment: You can also give `position: related; z-index: -1;` to the page wrapper when the popup triggered, but not the `<body>` tag (that may make your popup messed up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a DIV over the whole page when the iframe is open.

```
<div class="cover"></div>


.cover {
     position:fixed;
     top:0;
     bottom:0;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     z-index:2;
     color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
}
```

...just give your iframe a higher z-index.

Comment: So that would not allow the user to access the background links ?

Comment: Right. They'll end up clicking the overlay, which has no events bound to it.